# Google map polyline-draws-extra-line

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm using google map javascript polyline drawing using the below code

```
var flightPath = new google.maps.Polyline({
                path: BeatPath,
                geodesic: true,
                strokeColor: '#0077ff',
                strokeOpacity: 1.0,
                strokeWeight: 5
            });

            flightPath.setMap(map);
```

It drawing the path correctly but adding extra line to the starting point how to remove that ? in the screenshot you can see the result , marked in red is wrong , marked in green is correct , how to avoid the unwanted line ? [image: Marked in Red is wrong marked in green is correct]  [image]

Comment: Showing your BeatPath polyline variable might help or provide a fiddle link. Can you provide a [mcve]

Comment: working sample https://jsfiddle.net/8cdtaby9/9/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

List of array not in a descending order , this has been fixed by changing the list order by timestamp